# Error reading characters of string, VSCommunity2015

Tags: c++

No matter what I do, the Visual Studio Community 2015 debugger tells me that `it cannot read the characters of a string (res_path)` I declared:

```
bool loadBMP() {

    bool success = true;

    std::string res_path = "res\\pixelhome.bmp";

    bmp = SDL_LoadBMP(res_path.c_str());

    if (bmp == NULL) {

        std::cout << "SDL_IMAGE_ERROR: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

        success = false;

    }

    return success;
}
```

I also tried to set `res_path` to `NULL` and then setting the string to `"res\\pixelhome.bmp"` but got the same error. What am I missing?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MctRH.png)

Comment: Is the `res` in the same folder as `.vcproj` file? Not in the same folder with `.exe`

Comment: When does the debugger say this?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? Are you in Debug Configuration? If you're in Release, you might not be able to see the content of some variables (due to optimization).

Comment: what operating system and what string encoding are you using?

Comment: Also consider using forward slashes `/` in the paths. SDL might very well re-interpret the string and thus remove the backslashes.

Comment: The debugger says this when I declare the string res_path. I'm running this on WIndows 10, but I'm not sure how to find string encoding. I'll edit to add the exact error message.

Comment: Also, res is in the same folder as the .vcproj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it shows the content before initialization - that is, garbage.

Step to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping track of the `res_path` variable (Autos). This will look for the value of `res_path` in your current scope, which is before you declare the variable and set it to the value.

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to execute the line and have `res_path` assigned a value.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but now I'm getting that bmp = NULL. The res folder is in the same directory as the .vcproj folder.